# Use NLog to populate pre-exisiting log tables in SQLDB

Tags: nlog

I have been doing a bunch of searching on this and have come up blank. My research has shown me that i can use NLog to record logs to the DB but this always involves creating a new table with specific columns and stored procedures.

I have about 10 different systems, each with its own custom build logging functions and database tables. What i am looking to do is replace our current custom build logging logic with NLog. But i need NLog to then use my existing tables and schema to store the log. I can not modify the log tables in any way as they are tightly strapped to other functions that i can change at this time. So i need NLog to conform to my log table schema.

Is this even possible with NLog?

Any details would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: nLog can use any table schema you want.

Comment: @PaulAbbott thanks for the reply. Are you able to point me to a reference or technical doc that outlines how this is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Database-target

Your configuration would look something like:

```xml
<target name="db"
        xsi:type="Database"
        connectionStringName="NLogConn"
        commandText="INSERT INTO MyExistingTable (FieldA, FieldB, FieldC) VALUES (@a, @b, @c)">
  <parameter name="@a" layout="${machinename}" />
  <parameter name="@b" layout="${date}" />
  <parameter name="@c" layout="${exception:tostring}" />
</target>
```

The `layout` is anything from https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Layout-Renderers or a combination thereof.  You can also define multiple schema by adding different targets with different names.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like what i need... I appreciate it.